# Test convergence of the integral $\int_0 ^{+ \infty} t^{-\alpha} e ^ {-\cos t} \cdot \sin (t ^ \beta)dt$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

I'm given the integral
$$\int_0 ^{+ \infty} \frac{e ^ {-\cos t} \cdot \sin (t ^ \beta)}{t^\alpha} dt \qquad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$

and I need to test the absolute convergence. I split it in two parts, namely
$$\int_0 ^{1} \frac{e ^ {-\cos t} \cdot \sin (t ^ \beta)}{t^\alpha} dt + \int_1 ^{+ \infty} \frac{e ^ {-\cos t} \cdot \sin (t ^ \beta)}{t^\alpha} dt$$
and proved that the second part converge absolutely $\iff \alpha > 0$. So I examined the first part: the integral is bounded by
$$ e \int_0 ^{1} \frac{\sin (t ^ \beta)}{t^\alpha} dt$$but now I'm facing some difficulties:

- $\alpha \ge \beta +2 \Rightarrow $ divergence
- how to test if $\alpha < \beta +2 \Rightarrow $ absolute convergence

As @Tom-Tom noticed
$$e \int_0 ^{1} \frac{\sin (t ^ \beta)}{t^\alpha} dt < e \int_0 ^{1} \frac{t ^ \beta}{t^\alpha} dt = e \int_0 ^{1} t ^ {\beta - \alpha} dt = \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha} \cdot \left( 1 - \lim_{t \to 0} t ^ {\beta - \alpha + 1} \right)$$
so the integral $e \int_0 ^{1} \frac{\sin (t ^ \beta)}{t^\alpha} dt$ converge $\iff \beta - \alpha + 1 > 0 \iff \alpha < \beta + 1$

Comment: Hint: for $x\in\mathbb R$, $x-\frac{x^3}6\leq\sin x\leq x$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom can I end the proof by showing that
$$e \int \limits_0 ^{1} \frac{\sin (t ^ \beta)}{t^\alpha} dt < e \int \limits_0 ^{1} \frac{t ^ \beta}{t^\alpha} dt = e \int \limits_0 ^{1} t ^ {\beta - \alpha} dt = \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha} \cdot \left( 1 - \lim_{t \to 0} t ^ {\beta - \alpha + 1} \right)$$
converge $\iff \beta - \alpha + 1 \ge 0 \iff \alpha \le \beta + 1$ ?

Comment: Almost : you should specify $\alpha<\beta+1$ with strict inequality because $\int_0x^{-1}\mathrm dx$ diverges.